# Why android sdk hasn't support for many new elements?

Tags: android, material-design

In the last few days, i was trying to study the android's new Material Design. In the official doc, they suggest new element and various interactions.

But, for example, why don't they provide some simple support to raised/floating action buttons? Same to many other things, seems like they just want to suggest you the way to do it without providing real support on how to do them.

This way i end using tons of third libraries to support many of the new elements style and feels a bad idea.

Sorry for my bad english but just want to understand why can't they supply some support to the design they suggest.